# VB6 ADODB.Recordset RecordCount property always returns -1

Tags: sql-server, database, vb6, ado, adodb

I am trying to get some old VB6 code to work with SQL Server Compact.

I can connect, open the database and all seems well.  I can run insert select commands which work.

However the ADODB.Recordset RecordCount property always returns -1 even though I can access the Fields and see the data.  Changing the CursorLocation = adUseClient causes a problem when executung the SQL (multiple-step operation generated errors).

```vb
Option Explicit
    Private Const mSqlProvider          As String = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;"
    Private Const mSqlHost              As String = "Data Source=C:\Database.sdf;"
    Private mCmd                        As ADODB.Command   ' For executing SQL
    Private mDbConnection               As ADODB.Connection


Private Sub Command1_Click()


   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


    Dim DbConnectionString As String

    DbConnectionString = mSqlProvider & _
                            mSqlHost


    Set mDbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    mDbConnection.CursorLocation = adUseServer

    Call mDbConnection.Open(DbConnectionString)

    If mDbConnection.State = adStateOpen Then
        Debug.Print (" Database is open")
        ' Initialise the command object
        Set mCmd = New ADODB.Command
        mCmd.ActiveConnection = mDbConnection

        mCmd.CommandText = "select * from myTestTable"
        mCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

        Set rs = mCmd.Execute

        Debug.Print rs.RecordCount  ' Always returns -1  !!
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(0)   ' returns correct data for first row, first col
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(1)   ' returns correct data for first row, 2nd col
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(2)   ' returns correct data for first row, 3rd col

    End If

End Sub
```

Any advice would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 9):

Actually the `CursorLocation` plays a major role in this case. Use `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient` to set the cursor location and try.

```vb
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Dim DbConnectionString As String

    DbConnectionString = mSqlProvider & _
                            mSqlHost


    Set mDbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    mDbConnection.CursorLocation = adUseServer

    Call mDbConnection.Open(DbConnectionString)

    If mDbConnection.State = adStateOpen Then
        Debug.Print (" Database is open")
        ' Initialise the command object
        Set mCmd = New ADODB.Command
        mCmd.ActiveConnection = mDbConnection

        mCmd.CommandText = "select * from myTestTable"
        mCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

        Set rs = mCmd.Execute

        Debug.Print rs.RecordCount  ' This should now return the right value.
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(0)   ' returns correct data for first row, first col
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(1)   ' returns correct data for first row, 2nd col
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(2)   ' returns correct data for first row, 3rd col

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Though CursorLocation drives the behaviour, it is equally dependent upon the driver you are using. Actually rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient allows the cursors of the driver to be used. See the documentation of the driver you are using (Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5) for its cursor capabilities. The CE driver might not provide it. In that case, you might look for an upgraded driver.

Comment: Can you set the CursorLocation property of the connection object as well?

Comment: set to aduseserver THE CONNECTION not the recordset. Use new/other  connection

Answer (score 3):

That's a result of the type of cursor used to access the data, this post covers the issue and possible fixes.

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14143

**EDIT**

I apologize for not being more attentive to the fact that you were dealing with Compact. With Compact the situation is similar to the one I referenced, as it uses forward only cursors by default (which do not support row count) but there are two other cursor types available as documented in the link below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272067

Comment: tried both methods and both failed to execute "select * from myTestTable".  Incidentally, if I open the sdf via Sql Server Management Studio 2008 the sql works and returns 11 rows.

Answer (score 3):

From memory with working with VB6/ADO a long time ago the .RecordCount field doesn't return meaningful data until you've moved to the end of the recordset.

```
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
```

Though with this you'll need to make sure you have the appropriate cursor type (i.e., not forward only).

The only other solution I can think of is to do a separate SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTestTable, etc but this has issues with the data changing between that call, and the one that actually returns the rows.

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this..

```vb
Set rs = mCmd.Execute

rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF = true

    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount  ' Always returns -1  !!
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0)   ' returns correct data for first row, first col
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(1)   ' returns correct data for first row, 2nd col
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(2)   ' returns correct data for first row, 3rd col

   counter = counter + 1
   rs.MoveNext

Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

With Compact the default cursor attribute is adOpenForwardOnly for improved performance.  As such RecordCount is returned as "-1" which means its not available, rather than blank.  This is by design because the # of records in a dynamic cursor could change and result in pinging back and forth between the client server to maintain accuracy.  However, if the record count is vital try setting it to use adOpenKeyset or adOpenStatic with a server-side cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Check Recordset Property

The follow is result that RecordCount value returned by com.status.live code

```
+------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
|    CursorTypeEnum|adOpenForwardOnly=0|dOpenKeyset=1|adOpenDynamic=2|adOpenStatic=3|
|CursorLocationEnum|                                                                |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
|adUseServer = 2   |         X         |      O      |       X       |       O      |
|adUseClient = 3   |         O         |      O      |       O       |       O      |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for you that I used

```vb
Dim recordnumber As Long
Dim SalRSrec As New ADODB.Recordset
Set SalRSrec = Nothing
SalRSrec.Open ("SELECT count(*) from SALARY where EMPID= '" & cmb_empid & "' ;"), Dbase, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
recordnumber = SalRSrec.GetString
MsgBox recordnumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Set rs = mCmd.Execute` with:

```
set rs = new ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "select * from myTestTable", mDBConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

The `adOpenDynamic` will allow a forward/backward read through to get your recordcount.

Comment: I tried this but get an error when I run rs.open: "Errors Occurred. [,,,,,,]"

Comment: the error that occurred is the one I mentioned in my comment. As I stepped over rs.open it said "Errors Occurred. [,,,,,,]" which is not very detailed!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using following code if still returns -1

```vb
Set Conn = createobject("ADODB.connection")
Set Rs = createobject("ADODB.recordset")
Conn.Open "DSN=DSN_QTP" 
'Rs.Open "Select * From orders",Conn,adOpenDynamic,adLockBatchOptimistic
Rs.Open "Select * from [QTP-Table]",Conn,1 'Use either 1 or 3
'I tried using adopendynamic but it still returned -1. Using 1 it gave me correct count.       'Though I am using this code in QTP (Vbscript) same should work for VB6 also.
msgbox Rs.RecordCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help you,

```vb
set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
conn.open "<connection string>" 
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
sql = "SELECT columns FROM table WHERE [...]" 
rs.open sql,conn,1,1 
if not rs.eof then 
    nr = rs.recordcount 
    response.write "There were " & nr & " matches." 
    ' ... process real results here ... 
else 
    response.write "No matches." 
end if 
rs.close: set rs = nothing 
conn.close: set conn = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

strVerb = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\test.accdb"

tab1 = "tabelle1"

strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) FROM " & tab1

Debug.Print strSQL
         
cn.Open strVerb
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)

Debug.Print rs.Fields(0)
    
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

you must set the CONNECTIOn to aduseClient, no  recordset
and be carefoul to set only a new connection, if you use the same connection in your proyect, you can get other errors.

CRAETE A NEW CONNEXTION with aduseclient

```
Dim Sql As String
Dim CnCommand As New ADODB.Connection

On Error GoTo VerError:
Dim Comando As ADODB.Command
Set Comando = New ADODB.Command
CnCommand.ConnectionString = Cn.ConnectionString 'your exist connection in application
CnCommand.Open
CnCommand.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Set Comando.ActiveConnection = CnCommand

'Comando.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    
    Comando.Parameters.Append Comando.CreateParameter("@Usuario", adInteger, adParamInput, , V_General.Usuario.Codigo)
    
    Comando.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    
    Comando.CommandText = "SP_Contratac"
    Dim Rs As Recordset
    Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set Rs = Comando.Execute()
```

Answer (score -1):

This following code returns the recortcount exactly...

```vb
Public Sub test()
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection()
    Dim sPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    sPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath)

    If sPath.EndsWith("\bin") Then
        sPath = sPath.Substring(0, Len(sPath) - 4)
    End If

    Dim DbConnectionString As String
    DbConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" & sPath & "\students.mdb"

    cn.ConnectionString = DbConnectionString
    cn.Open()

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()
    rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
    rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic
    rs.Open("select * from students", cn)
    MsgBox(rs.RecordCount)

    rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: this uses a Access database, not a SDF database.