# Recordset always returns -1 (excel VBA)

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, vba

I want to count the number of rows returned by a query in a recordset, I tried `recset.RecordCount` function but it always return a value of `-1`.

How am I going to count the number of records or rows in recordset?

Answer (score 4):

It is important to specify parameter: CursorLocation = adUseClient in connection object.

```
dbName = "DbInjectorsCatalog"
dbFilePath = "C:\DbInjectorsCatalog.mdf"
 
connStr = "Driver={SQL Server native Client 11.0};" & _
          "Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" & _
          "AttachDBFileName=" & dbFilePath & ";" & _
          "Database=" & dbName & ";" & _
          "Trusted_Connection=Yes"
sqlStr = "Select * from Injectors"
 
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = connStr

'>>> scpecify cursor location
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

conn.Open
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sqlStr, connStr, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
```

Full working example is here:
http://straightitsolutions.blogspot.com/2014/12/read-recordcount-from-adodbrecordset.html

Answer (score 2):

have you tried moving to the last before checking for count

```
recset.MoveLast
```

also see if this helps

> The RecordCount property will return -1 for a forward-only cursor; the
>   actual count for a static or keyset cursor; and either -1 or the
>   actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on the data source.

Check this question:

[VB6 ADODB.Recordset RecordCount property always returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282661/vb6-adodb-recordset-recordcount-property-always-returns-1)

Comment: You still need back to the beginning though or else you'll not be able to read the data.

Comment: I try to use recset.MoveLast but then an error prompts that :"Rowset does not support fetching backward"

Answer (score 1):

**can you try adding this:**

```
objRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRS.Open strSQL, objConn,,adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

**The Cursor position is important.**

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly a recordset count isn't populated until you move to the end.  I believe (dredging my memory here) that it is something like

```
MyRecordSet.MoveLast
MyRecordSet.MoveFirst
```

Then your count should be populated

Comment: These returns an error that prompts "Rowset does not support fetching backward".

Comment: This should help - its because your recordset is opened as "forwardOnly" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122308/rowset-does-not-support-scrolling-backward

Comment: Just don't call MoveFirst. I guess the error is being thrown there?